# How to display only the direct children of a term on a taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy, children

I would like to have a couple of (automatically generated) taxonomy pages created by term name, term description *and* a listing of only the next level of subterms. (No parents and no grandchildrens)

I have set up a CPT named "Products", and a custom hierarchical taxonomy called "Structure". The taxonomy has the hierarchical terms

```
level1a
level1b
-level2a
-level2b
--level3a
--level4a
level1c
...
```

I'm trying to achieve to get taxonomy pages of /level1a/ and /level1b/level2a/ and so on.

On each of these pages there should be the term-title, the term-description and a list of direct child-terms of the current term. (No grandchildren).

In functions.php I have created the CPT with the

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false),
```

option and the custom taxonomy with the

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false),
```

option.

I am now struggling with the correct query in taxonomy.php to get the direct children only.

The closest i found is

```
<?php
$taxonomy_name = get_queried_object()->taxonomy; // Get the name of the taxonomy
$term_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Get the id of the taxonomy
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name ); // Get the children of said taxonomy
// Display the children
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

But this is showing all children and grandchildren

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hmmm I'm not familiar with `get_term_children` it looks like a helper method. Perhaps it would be better to skip the middleman and go direct to `WP_Term_Query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the current term id by the following code

```
 $current_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Getting all the info of chilldren of the parent, not grandchildren

```
$termchildren = array(
   'hierarchical' => 1,
   'show_option_none' => '',
   'hide_empty' => 0,
   'parent' => $current_term_id ,
   'taxonomy' => 'Structure'
);

$subcats = get_categories($termchildren);
```

// Display the children

```
   foreach ($subcats as $key => $value) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $value );
        $name = $value->name;
        echo '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$name.'</a>';
   }
```